# Screen will not lock automatically 12.10

Tags: 12.10, lock-screen

Since upgrading to 12.10 I cannot get my screen to lock automatically. I am using GDM at home and LightDM at work and neither will lock automatically. However, when I issue <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> on either system, the screen will lock as it should.

It is set to turn the display off after 5 minutes and lock screen when screen turns off. Require Password is set also. Display turns off after 5 minutes but no locking occurs.

I am using Unity with Compiz on both systems. Not sure what other things might be involved.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I'm considering filing a bug...

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: The package you should file this bug for is `gnome-screensaver`

Comment: More specifically (as it's not easy to find by navigating): https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screensaver